# How to run "Rise of Nations" with wine?

Tags: wine

I can't install "Rise of Nations" expansion pack (2 CDs) with wine.

I see a message

```
pidgen.dll cannot load
```

If you have a solution, could you please explain it very clearly so that I can follow?

Comment: At the very least, we need to know what version of Ubuntu you're using and what version of Wine you have.  If you haven't already, you should check at http://appdb.winehq.org to see what their testing shows for *Rise of Nations*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 13.10, install playonlinux instead of using Wine directly. That should make things significantly easier for you. If you are not using Ubuntu 13.04, you may download playonlinux here: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by installing MSXML4 / vcrun6 / corefonts / mfc42 / .NET 1.1 thru 3.5 (should be one of those) managed to get past that error and install the game, just not able run it now due to a msxml4 fatal error on launch.